# About using System.NoErrMsg

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-xe4

I am studying about [System.NoErrMsg](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.NoErrMsg) in C++ Builder XE4.

From the documents, I infer that by setting NoErrMsg true, I will not see the error MessageBox.

Following is my sample code.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    NoErrMsg = true; // System.NoErrMsg

    StrToInt(" "); // make the error purposely
}
```

However, still the above code shows the Error MessageBox when I click Button1.

Is my understanding of NoErrMsg incorrect?

How is it normally used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NoErrMsg` applies to [runtime errors](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Delphi_Runtime_Errors), such as I/O errors and OS errors. `StrToInt()` raises an exception instead.  Not the same thing, and `NoErrMsg` does not apply to uncaught exceptions.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not recognize what you pointed out. I appreciate it.